# Fixed Length Variadic Parameter Packs in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm attempting to implement a generalized n-dimensional vector class using C++11. Ideally, I'd like to provide the type "T" and number of dimensions "n" of the vector and have the constructor accept the appropriate number of arguments.

Unfortunately, I've been unable to find a way to allow a template-specified fixed length of a parameter pack.

What I'm looking for is something like

```
template<typename T, size_t n>
class Vector {
public:
    Vector(T... values /* values is exactly n parameters long */);

    ...
};
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: There's `std::array` for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, you can use std::enable_if:

```
template <typename... Args,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        sizeof...(Args) == n
    >::type>
explicit Vector(Args&&... values) : _data{ std::forward<Args>(values)... } {}
```

It will shadow constructors that may accept size of Args other than n.

Comment: Interesting. Could you explain exactly what is happening in the constructor initialization list? I'm fairly new to the C++11 standard and am having a hard time figuring out how this works. Thanks!

Comment: It is just simple move constructor. I assumed __data is defined like this: T __data[n]; the initializer list simply moves values from constructor arguments to the __data array. You should read about std::move, it is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use this trick:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t n, typename = std::make_index_sequence<n>>
class Vector;

template <typename T, std::size_t n, std::size_t... Ignore>
class Vector<T, n, std::index_sequence<Ignore...>>
{
    template <size_t > using ith_T = T;
public:
    Vector(ith_T<Ignore>... values)
    {
    }
};
```

This will ensure that `Vector` takes `n` arguments of type `T`, no additional templating necessary. You could additionally hide the `Ignore...` ugliness in a namespace:

```
namespace details {
    template <typename T, std::size_t n, typename = std::make_index_sequence<n>>
    class Vector;

    ...
}

template <typename T, std::size_t n>
using Vector = details::Vector<T, n>;
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit what happens here?

Comment: @Kikohs A pack is created of the right length (through a default argument and `make_index_sequence`).  This pack is pattern matched by the specialization.  This pack is then unpacked in a way that each instance becomes the type `T`.  We get a ctor that asks for exactly `n` instances of `T`.  I don't like Barry's use of `details::make` (Why use `decltype` at all?  `template<std::size_t I> using ith_T=T; Vector(ith_T<Ignore>...)`), and if the end-user passes a flawed 3rd argument things get dicy, but other than that, it works.

Comment: @Yakk That is dramatically better, yes.